# Mui react menu transition

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, menu

I try to add Mui menu in my site and add transition effect from right side but its not working and

```
<Menu transitionDuration={1}open={Open} onClose={Close} MenuListProps={} className="nav">
     <MenuItem >Home</MenuItem> 
     <MenuItem >About</MenuItem> 
     <MenuItem >Contact</MenuItem> 
</Menu>
```

how to add **transition effect from right side** in this code i am new in react and Mui, Now its default style will show and i change the transition durations to 5 but its not working

Answer (score 0):

the menu component in mui has some parameter such as anchorOrigin and anchorPosition which you can use to give position to your popup menuItem
this can probebly help you: ...

```
<Menu 
transitionDuration={1}
open={Open} 
onClose={Close} 
anchorEl={anchorElNav} 
 MenuListProps={} 
className="nav"
anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 500,
          horizontal: "left",
            }}
keepMounted
transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 400,
        horizontal: "right",
           }}
>
     <MenuItem >Home</MenuItem> 
     <MenuItem >About</MenuItem> 
     <MenuItem >Contact</MenuItem> 

</Menu>
```